# Use Google Fused Location API in background to track distance

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

For a school project, i have to do an Android project (i am new to Android coding) where i must track the user location and record his travelled distance.
For this, i use the Google Fused Location API.

I am having good results concerning the tracking, but it is only working when the app is in the foreground.

I have to continue to track the user location even when the phone is sleeping, and calculate his travelled distance.

I made some researches and found some solutions with `AlarmManager`, or with the `requestLocationUpdates` using `PendingIntent`. But i can't figure out what is the best to use in my situation.

The "only" thing i want to do while the phone is sleeping is to continue getting his location and increment a float with his distance, so i can update the UI when the user is back on the app screen with his correct distance travelled.

What is the best way to do this in my case ?

Thank for your answers.

Comment: search for backgrond service for location updates. This will be a background service which will be keep running in background and listen the location updates at regular interval and then you can save it or update it in your storage.

Comment: Should i have "two" location updaters to do that ? The one i use already for the foreground use and the second for background (and disable the foreground one while i am in background state) or only use the service for both ?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple location updaters as per requirements, but if background service gives you result no need to have multiple one as both will have same result.